# Match two data-frames by common column and fill in data from adjacent columns

Tags: r

Let's say I have a dataframe `df2015` that contains a column called `county_fips`.  I have another dataframe named `ffl2015` that contains a column called `county_fips` and another column called `ffl_cnt`.

What is the right way to essentially paste the values contained in `ffl_cnt` to all the corresponding entries of `county_fips` in `df2015`

My attempt at a merge seemed to add a bunch of unnecessary rows:

```
merge(ffl2015[, c("county_fips", "ffl_cnt")], df2015,by = "county_fips")
```

Comment: What do you mean by unnecessary rows? Your posted command performs an inner join so the result should be the set of intersecting rows (by `county_fps`) between `ffl2015` and `df2015`. Can you post some input data and desired (or even problematic output) that illustrate your issue?

Comment: As @aichao said your code should already add the `ffl_cnt` values in a rearranged order to correspond to how `county_fips` in `ffl2015`is rearranged when matched to `county_fips` in the other data frame. Do you want the values in `ffl_cnt` to *replace* the ones in `county_fips` rather than staying as an extra column?

Comment: I think I'm probably confused somewhere.  There is no "ffl_cnt" column in the df2015 dataset.  I want to generate a new column "ffl_cnt" in the df2015 dataset based upon the shared column of "county_fips" between ffl2015 and df2015.  For every "county_fips" that is matched, I want to extract the corresponding "ffl_cnt" located in ffl2015 and paste that over to df2015.

Comment: Your `merge` should do exactly that if you set its output to `df2015`. That is: `df2015 <- merge(ffl2015[, c("county_fips", "ffl_cnt")], df2015,by = "county_fips")`. Let me ask this question: are `county_fips` values unique in both `df2015` and `ffl2015`? Is there more rows in `df2015` or in `ffl2015`?

Comment: There are more rows in `ffl2015.`  In neither dataframe are `county_fips` unique.  `county_fips` simply identifies which county a given mass shooting happened in (contained in `df2015`).  ffl2015 contains the total number of federal firearm licenses per county.

Comment: Apply an index to within county_fips mass shootings? And aggregate ff12050 at the county_fips level will/should give you equivalent number of entries for county_fips and aggregated firearm licenses per county.